# Streaming output from make called by cmake

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I am calling make in a cmake custom command (I have to bridge between a CMake build and a legacy make build). Everything works fine, except one thing: Instead of seeing the output of the make build live on stdout, it only gets flushed after the build finishes. I have searched online but couldn't find a solution so far. What could the cause for such a behavior be?

I tested this modified simple example which recursively calls itself. This does behave exactly how I expect. I see the echos from the recursive calls as they happen. I can't figure out what the difference to my actual code is:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(Wrapper
    PREFIX "Wrapper"
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 5
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env FOO=BAR ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -C "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    BUILD_ALWAYS ON
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

My actual code, which only shows the output after the external make build is completely finished:

```
ExternalProject_Add(Wrapper
    PREFIX "Wrapper"
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${target_files} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env ASM_OPT="${CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS}" CC_OPT="${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" CPP_OPT="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -C "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.." -f Makefile.mak -O -j 4
    BUILD_ALWAYS ON
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    DEPENDS ${ALL_LIBS}
)
```

Comment: So, your second `COMMAND` calls `make` from the **current build directory**. But `make` is already active: it builds your CMake project. Shouldn't you specify proper current directory for `make`? E.g. with `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option of `add_custom_command`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I deleted that part from the code snippet as the working directory has nothing to with the console output. The issue I face is that the output seems to get buffered and only shown after that command (both actually, I think) complete.

Comment: What if you replace `${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}` with `sleep 5` or similar, would the output be still delated?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated the question with a simple self-contained version that DOES work as I expect, and my current version which does NOT work as expected for some reason I can't figure out.

Comment: @kutschkem Better not to hardcode `-j 4` in the CLI. You can use [`cmake_host_system_information`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_host_system_information.html) to get number of cores.

Comment: @zaufi I hate to ask this, but does it make more sense to use the logical or physical cores to control that? I intend to use half of the available cores. I am assuming logical?

Comment: @kutschkem Example, `/proc/cpuinfo` has _logical_ cores, hence setting `-jN` means logical cores.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: In the case of other than `Unix Makefiles` generator (e.g., `Ninja`, the `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable gonna have a path to underlaid build system tool (e.g., `/usr/bin/ninja` for `Ninja` generator :)

A better way is to use [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to build your non-CMake (third party) project.

Or, since CMake 3.18 `execute_process` got the `ECHO_OUTPUT_VARIABLE` named keyword (option) which is equal to *nix `tee` command...

Comment: I am switching to ExternalProject and custom ExternalProject steps (I can't figure out how to properly control the working directory otherwise), but it has the same problem.

Comment: @zaufi: "In the case of other than `Unix Makefiles` generator (e.g., Ninja, the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM variable gonna be empty" - Are you sure about that? CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) states that the variable is set for many well-known generators.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah, you're right... I tried to say that for other generators this variable gonna be smth else than just path to GNU Make... Meaning that, the custom target which tries to build smth w/ GNU Make most likely gonna be failed...

Comment: E.g., for the updated question and `-G Ninja` on CMake run: `ninja -f Makefile.mak` obviously incorrect %) @kutschkem For the other generators you need to `find_program()` to look for `make`/`gmake` and then use it

Comment: @kutschkem `ExternalProject` uses `execute_process`  internally. And all that calls, obviously, don't use the `ECHO_OUTPUT_VARIABLE` option... That is why.